# How to interrupt input after 30 seconds and quit from program? - automatic logout - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I would like to make automatic logout after 30 seconds. 
Program waits for user to input something and after 30 seconds I would like program to automatically shut down.
I have something like this:

```
import sys, time, os

def start_controller(user):

   start = time.time()
   PERIOD_OF_TIME = 30
   os.system('clear')
   print_menu()                            #printing menu
   choice = get_choice()                   #get input from view model
   while choice != "0":
       os.system('clear')
       if choice == "1":
           start += PERIOD_OF_TIME
           print_student_list(Student.student_list,AllAttendance.all_attendance_list)
       if time.time() > start + PERIOD_OF_TIME:
         os.system("clear")
         print('logout')
         Database.save_all_data_to_csv()
         sys.exit()
```

Comment: move `if time.time() > start + PERIOD_OF_TIME:` to while block

Comment: Does the `get_choice` function block ? meaning, is that the one waiting for the user input ? Also what if they enter a different value ? should it still exit after the timeout ?

Comment: Yes, get_choice() is returning input(). I would like timer to start when I start start_controller() and if I don't do anything, after 30 seconds it should exit.

Comment: I can see that you are checking for a value of "1". but you don't show any errors if it's different than "1", and you don't ask for a different choice from the user again. so, how is that part supposed to work ? PS: use `@username` when replying to a specific user's comment so they get a notification.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of using threads to get and process user input with a timeout.

We create a Timer thread to perform the timeout function, and wait for the user input in a daemon thread. If the user supplies an input string within the nominated delay period then the Timer is cancelled, otherwise the Timer will set the `finished` Event to break the `while` loop. If you need to do any final cleanup, you can do that after the `while` loop.

```
from threading import Thread, Timer, Event

def process_input(timer):
    s = input('> ')
    timer.cancel()
    print(s.upper())

delay = 30
finished = Event()
while not finished.isSet():
    timer = Timer(delay, finished.set)
    worker = Thread(target=process_input, args=(timer,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()
    timer.start()
    timer.join()
```